# Create multiple connection pools dynamically

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0, apache-commons-dbcp

I am connecting with multiple datasources i.e. Hive, Oracle, Netezza, etc via JDBC and performing some DDL and DML queries.

I tried multiple tools for connection pooling. I started with `HikariCP1` *(because it's still active)*, but got some issue with hive *(needed hive 2.0.0 jar)*.

So, I tried `c3p0` and `commons-dbcp`, both are working.

**c3p0:**

```
private static Connection getJdbcConnection(String connectionUri, String username,
        String password) throws SQLException {

    ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    cpds.setJdbcUrl(connectionUri);
    cpds.setUser(username);
    cpds.setPassword(password);
    return cpds.getConnection(); 
}
```

**dbcp:**

```
private static Connection getJdbcConnection(String connectionUri, String username,
        String password) throws SQLException {

    BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
    bds.setUrl(connectionUri);
    bds.setUsername(username);
    bds.setPassword(password);  
    return bds.getConnection(); 
}
```

Now I need to support multiple data sources. I want to make a separate pool for each datasource *(separate for hive and oracle)*.

**I can not create pools beforehand because I don't have any prior information about connection uri and credentials.**

How to achieve this using c3p0 or dbcp?

Comment: Your example code creates a pool, gets a connection and then throws away the pool. That is of course not going to work. You could for example store them in a map with the connection url + user name in as the key.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank. Yes, I will reuse the connections. I just started with the tool.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel any point on creating multiple pools?

Comment: I don't really understand what problem you are having with dynamically creating multiple pools. But otherwise: see my suggestion in my previous comment, and otherwise try to explain what you have already tried, and what hurdles you see.